# Upper body conditioning goals

Tags: conditioning

I like training towards reaching certain goals rather than just training for the sake of training. It makes it easier for me to try getting into shape doing that.

For the lower body, I have some concrete goals like doing a 5k in less than 20 minutes and doing 100 burpees in less than eight minutes. However, I am not sure what to aim for in the case of the upper body. I have access to rowing machines and will soon also have access to battle ropes. I also have access to pull-ups and dips bars.

What are some great goals I can aim to achieve for my torso and arms?

Comment: Do you have access to a pull-up bar or a thing you can use to pull yourself up?

Comment: Rowing or kayaking goals?

Comment: @DeeV Yes, I do

Answer (score 1):

The very basics are:

- x number of strict form pull ups. This is a standard military fitness tests and a practical movement which trains your shoulders, wrists (grip), and upper back
- x number of strict form push ups. Push ups are present on virtually every decent fitness tests. If you can do over 50 push ups (controlled descent to floor to lockout), you can look at the bench press
- Wall handstand push up or x over-head presses at y weight.
- x number of dips.

Answer (score 1):

**What ever the goal should be depends on what you want to achieve more than anything else.**

You can do numerous things like that "100 burpees in under 8 minutes" goal for your upper body.

- 'x' amount of strict pull-ups
- 'x' amount of strict push-ups
- 'x' amount of dips
- 'x' amount of muscle-ups or weighted pull-ups (when you've reached the pull-up goal)
- Holding an L-sit position while hanging for 'x' amount of time

You can also set goals to certain exercises if you have the equipment like 'x' amount of weight on the deadlift, squat, bench press, shoulder press.